# Confused by Kolmogorov's Strong law and Borel-Cantelli lemma

Tags: probability, statistics

**Notation:** Let $X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables with mean $\mathrm{E}[X_n]=\mu$ and variance $\mathrm{E}[(X_n-\mu)^2]=\sigma^2$. Denote the sample average as $\bar{x}_m = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^m X_n$.

Accoring to (my interpretation of) Kolmogorov's SLLN since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sigma^2/n^2$ converges then $\mathrm{P}\{\bar{x}_n-\mu>\epsilon, \mathrm{i.o}\} = 0, \forall \epsilon>0$.

**Question:** Does this mean that (due to Borel-Cantelli lemma) the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathrm{P}\{\bar{x}_n-\mu>\epsilon\}, \forall \epsilon>0$ converges?

Comment: Do you mean $|\bar x_n - \mu|$? Also, with Borel-Cantelli you can only show that series diverge (by contradiction), you can't apply this lemma directly to show convergence of the series.

Comment: I was thinking that if the above would have held for the event $\{|\bar{x}_n-\mu|>\epsilon\}$ then it would have also held for the event $\{\bar{x}_n-\mu>\epsilon\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Borel-Cantelli lemma alone does not guarantee this implication since, to prove the implication 
$$
P\left(\limsup\limits_nA_n\right)=0\implies\sum\limits_nP(A_n)\ \text{converges},
$$
one would use the part 
$$\sum\limits_nP(A_n)\ \text{diverges}\implies P\left(\limsup\limits_nA_n\right)=1,
$$
of Borel-Cantelli lemma, which requires the events $(A_n)$ to be independent. Unfortunately, here $A_n=[\bar x_n-\mu\gt\epsilon]$ hence the events $(A_n)$ are not independent.

Comment: Thanks Did and Ilya for the clarification!